# How do child functions resolve to their parents in recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

This is my first question, so I apologise in advance for any mistakes in my formatting. Recently, I've tried to tackle recursive problems and backtracking problems. While I seem to understand the basics underneath it, I'm having an extremely difficult time in visualising the call stack. I have this problem:"read in a number and find all possible combinations of positive numbers that add up to the given magical number".
This is what the output would look like:

```
input:
5
output:
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 2
1 4
2 3
5
```

This is the code for the problem:

```
def find_combinations(magical_number):
    def find_combinations_recursively(remaining, start, combination):
        if remaining == 0:
            # Print the combination
            print(" ".join(map(str, combination)))
            return

        for i in range(start, remaining + 1):
            combination.append(i)
            # Recursively find combinations
            find_combinations_recursively(remaining - i, i, combination)
            combination.pop()

    combination = []
    find_combinations_recursively(magical_number, 1, combination)
```

My question in relation to this problem is, how does the variable i increase in relation to the recursive calls, and how can I keep track of its incrementation as the recursion unfolds? I just find it hard to visualise it, even with pen and paper.Perhaps I've been doing it wrong? Is a tree structure appropriate? Thank you in advance for your help.

This is what I usually do to visualise the call stack (in this example the number is 3):

```
1. Initial Call:
   - find_combinations_recursively(3, 1, [])
     - Stack: [remaining=3, start=1, i=None, Parent=None]

2. First Iteration (i=1):
   - find_combinations_recursively(2, 1, [1])
     - Stack: [remaining=2, start=1, i=1, Parent=(3, 1, None)]
       - find_combinations_recursively(1, 1, [1, 1])
         - Stack: [remaining=1, start=1, i=1, Parent=(2, 1, 1)]
           - find_combinations_recursively(0, 1, [1, 1, 1])
             - Stack: [remaining=0, start=1, i=1, Parent=(1, 1, 1)]

   - find_combinations_recursively(0, 2, [1, 2])
     - Stack: [remaining=0, start=2, i=2, Parent=(2, 1, 1)]

3. Second Iteration (i=2):
   - find_combinations_recursively(2, 2, [2])
     - Stack: [remaining=2, start=2, i=2, Parent=(3, 1, None)]
       - find_combinations_recursively(0, 2, [2, 2])
         - Stack: [remaining=0, start=2, i=2, Parent=(2, 2, 2)]

4. Third Iteration (i=3):
   - find_combinations_recursively(3, 3, [3])
     - Stack: [remaining=3, start=3, i=3, Parent=(3, 1, None)]
       - find_combinations_recursively(0, 3, [3, 3])
         - Stack: [remaining=0, start=3, i=3, Parent=(3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: Yes a tree. From a node you then have start--remaining branches (local i vary from start to remaining, you can then label each arc with i. Each node containing start/remaining deduced from i the arc and start/remaining of the parent node.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a table where each column represents a stack frame (left to right). A tuple indicates what the local variables `remaining` and `start` have as values (they are local and never change value). The value of `i` is implicitly represented by showing the argument with which `append` is executed.

At the far right `combination` is represented, which is a single list to which all executions of `find_combinations_recursively` have access. An asterisk suffix means that combination is printed.

#### For input 5:

| depth 0 | depth 1 | depth 2 | depth 3 | depth 4 | depth 5 | combination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (5, 1) |  |  |  |  |  | [] |
| append 1 |  |  |  |  |  | [1] |
|  | (4, 1) |  |  |  |  | [1] |
|  | append 1 |  |  |  |  | [1, 1] |
|  |  | (3, 1) |  |  |  | [1, 1] |
|  |  | append 1 |  |  |  | [1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  | (2, 1) |  |  | [1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  | append 1 |  |  | [1, 1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  |  | (1, 1) |  | [1, 1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  |  | append 1 |  | [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  |  |  | (0, 1) | [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]* |
|  |  |  |  | pop |  | [1, 1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  | pop |  |  | [1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  | append 2 |  |  | [1, 1, 1, 2] |
|  |  |  |  | (0, 2) |  | [1, 1, 1, 2]* |
|  |  |  | pop |  |  | [1, 1, 1] |
|  |  | pop |  |  |  | [1, 1] |
|  |  | append 2 |  |  |  | [1, 1, 2] |
|  |  |  | (1, 2) |  |  | [1, 1, 2] |
|  |  | pop |  |  |  | [1, 1] |
|  |  | append 3 |  |  |  | [1, 1, 3] |
|  |  |  | (0, 3) |  |  | [1, 1, 3]* |
|  |  | pop |  |  |  | [1, 1] |
|  | pop |  |  |  |  | [1] |
|  | append 2 |  |  |  |  | [1, 2] |
|  |  | (2, 2) |  |  |  | [1, 2] |
|  |  | append 2 |  |  |  | [1, 2, 2] |
|  |  |  | (0, 2) |  |  | [1, 2, 2]* |
|  |  | pop |  |  |  | [1, 2] |
|  | pop |  |  |  |  | [1] |
|  | append 3 |  |  |  |  | [1, 3] |
|  |  | (1, 3) |  |  |  | [1, 3] |
|  | pop |  |  |  |  | [1] |
|  | append 4 |  |  |  |  | [1, 4] |
|  |  | (0, 4) |  |  |  | [1, 4]* |
|  | pop |  |  |  |  | [1] |
| pop |  |  |  |  |  | [] |
| append 2 |  |  |  |  |  | [2] |
|  | (3, 2) |  |  |  |  | [2] |
|  | append 2 |  |  |  |  | [2, 2] |
|  |  | (1, 2) |  |  |  | [2, 2] |
|  | pop |  |  |  |  | [2] |
|  | append 3 |  |  |  |  | [2, 3] |
|  |  | (0, 3) |  |  |  | [2, 3]* |
|  | pop |  |  |  |  | [2] |
| pop |  |  |  |  |  | [] |
| append 3 |  |  |  |  |  | [3] |
|  | (2, 3) |  |  |  |  | [3] |
| pop |  |  |  |  |  | [] |
| append 4 |  |  |  |  |  | [4] |
|  | (1, 4) |  |  |  |  | [4] |
| pop |  |  |  |  |  | [] |
| append 5 |  |  |  |  |  | [5] |
|  | (0, 5) |  |  |  |  | [5]* |
| pop |  |  |  |  |  | [] |

#### For input 3:

| depth 0 | depth 1 | depth 2 | depth 3 | combination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (3, 1) |  |  |  | [] |
| append 1 |  |  |  | [1] |
|  | (2, 1) |  |  | [1] |
|  | append 1 |  |  | [1, 1] |
|  |  | (1, 1) |  | [1, 1] |
|  |  | append 1 |  | [1, 1, 1] |
|  |  |  | (0, 1) | [1, 1, 1]* |
|  |  | pop |  | [1, 1] |
|  | pop |  |  | [1] |
|  | append 2 |  |  | [1, 2] |
|  |  | (0, 2) |  | [1, 2]* |
|  | pop |  |  | [1] |
| pop |  |  |  | [] |
| append 2 |  |  |  | [2] |
|  | (1, 2) |  |  | [2] |
| pop |  |  |  | [] |
| append 3 |  |  |  | [3] |
|  | (0, 3) |  |  | [3]* |
| pop |  |  |  | [] |

I hope this clarifies what happens.

Comment: It's a nice representation, though I'm having a bit of trouble analysing it due to the all the calls; perhaps it'd be easier with a smaller number, like 3?

Comment: Sure, but the principle is the same. Added the table for when input is 3

Comment: The main thing that confuses me about backtracking is what is being popped off the stack! If every recursive call is popped off the stack because of the .pop() statement, why are we appending a 2 in the 10th frame of depth 1, instead of just removing it? I mean, the first function call (3,1) should also do a pop(), right? Then how does the program stop there, increment the i, and add it to the list?

Comment: That's confusing. Let's get some things straight: the call stack is unrelated to the `.pop()` calls. There is no 10th frame. The frames stack on top of eachother (from left to right in the diagram), so that means that this `append 2` (on the 10th row of the table) happens in the *second* frame. The `append` and `pop` calls relate to the `combination` list (in the last column), not to stack frames.